# pgAdmin Editor Rails execute SQL from file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, pgadmin, file-encodings

Rails Code:

```
sql = File.read("#{Rails.root}/scripts/refresh.sql")

db_con = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
db_con.execute(sql)
```

file refresh.sql:

```
select 1;
```

If I create or modify file refresh.sql in pgAdmin (Ubuntu or Windows) I will get the following error:

```
PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "ï»¿select" 
LINE 1: ï»¿select 1;
```

However, if I copy and paste the sql text into a text editor (sublime or gedit) and overwrite file refresh.sql the code runs

Answer (score 0):

pgAdmin III main window
File => Options => Query file

Uncheck option "Read and write Unicode UTF-8 files"

[image]